# Adding predict_disable_shape_check=true as a parameter on LightGBM

Tags: python, parameters, lightgbm

In short, my initial df has a column that has probabilities from an external predictive model that I would like to compare to the predictions generated from my lightGBM model. First I used the train test split on my data, which included my column old_predictions

```
X = A, B, C, old_predictions

Y = outcome
seed=47
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2,random_state=seed)
```

I do not, however, want old_predictions to be included as a feature in my lightGBM model, so I made a separate df from the X_test data (which I will later append the light GBM prediction probabilities to) and dropped the old_predictions from the X_test and X_train

```
pred_df = X_test
X_test.drop(['old_predictions'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
X_train.drop(['old_predictions'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

When I try to train my model, however, I receive the following error:

```
LightGBMError: The number of features in data (4) is not the same as it was in training data (3).
You can set ``predict_disable_shape_check=true`` to discard this error, but please be aware what you are doing.
```

The two questions I have are

1. using the logic I described about why I dropped this variable, would you agree that it is indeed fine to disregard this error?
2. Where do I add predict_disable_shape_check=true to disregard the error? I have tried the below, but none have been successful and the same error reappears. I tried reading the docs but am having trouble finding clarity

```
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**parameters1, predict_disable_shape_check=True)
```

```
y_pred=model.predict(X_test, predict_disable_shape_check=True)
```

```
predictions = model.predict_proba(X_test, predict_disable_shape_check=True)[:, 1]
predictions_train = model.predict_proba(X_train, predict_disable_shape_check=True)[:, 1]
```

I have also added it directly to the parameters list and this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
y_pred=model.predict(X_test, predict_disable_shape_check=True)
```

Make sure X_test contains only the columns which were used to train the model.